# How to make lens flare ignore layers work with first person character in Unity 5?

Tags: unity, c#, lighting

I have a simple lens flare on my directional light (sun) and I would like the flare to only be visible when the sun is directly visible, naturally...But right now with the default ignore layers, the flare is only visible when 'Everything' is ticked. Obviously this therefore means you can see the flare through other objects which I don't want. I first thought that the camera must have been sitting 'inside' the standard assets first person character's collider, but it was definitely outside the collider so I don't see why it won't show...Could someone show me how to fix this? Thanks.